# Why does howSum solution work in Javascript but not in Python? (Dynamic programming)

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming, memoization

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65428535/why-does-this-solution-work-in-javascript-but-not-in-python-dynamic-programmin) asked on Stack Overflow.

*Write a function 'howSum(targetSum, numbers)' that takes in a targetSum and an array of numbers as arguments.*

*The function should return an array containing any combination of elements that add up to exactly the targetSum.*

*If there is no combination that adds up to the targetSum, then return None. If there are multiple combinations possible, you may return any single one.*

My memoized python code for the solution is as follows:

```
def howSum(targetSum, nums, memo = None):

    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
        
    if targetSum in memo: return memo[targetSum]
    if targetSum < 0: return None
    if targetSum == 0: return []
    
    for num in nums:
        remainder = targetSum - num
        remainderResult = howSum(remainder, nums)
        
        if remainderResult is not None:
            remainderResult.append(num)
            memo[targetSum] = remainderResult
            return memo[targetSum]
        
    memo[targetSum] = None
    return None

print(howSum(7, [2, 3])) # [3,2,2]
print(howSum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7])) # [4,3]
print(howSum(7, [2, 4])) # None
print(howSum(8, [2, 3, 5])) # [2,2,2,2]
print(howSum(300, [7,14]) # None
```

The algorithm works but not as efficiently for the final test case. In fact, the runtime efficiency is no different than the brute force solution. What's the problem?

Comment: Please include your runtime timings, also are you not memoizing based strictly on the sum (even if a different sequence is passed)? If you’re testing it on such small arrays there likely won’t be perceivable runtime difference no matter the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to pass the `memo` value to the recursive `howSum(remainder, nums)` call, so you're losing the benefit of memoizing there.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass memo when you call it recursively

```
def howSum(targetSum, nums, memo = None): 

if memo is None:
    memo = {}
    
if targetSum in memo: return memo[targetSum]
if targetSum < 0: return None
if targetSum == 0: return []

for num in nums:
    remainder = targetSum - num
    remainderResult = howSum(remainder, nums , memo ) #pass memo as well
    
    if remainderResult is not None:
        remainderResult.append(num)
        memo[targetSum] = remainderResult
        return memo[targetSum]
    
memo[targetSum] = None
return None
```

Comment: Question, why can't I pass memo = {} directly in the argument as def howSum(targetSum, nums, memo = {})

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing your answer array, that's why It is not working. Try this code:

```
hmap = {}
def howSum(targetSum, numbers,ans=[]):
    if targetSum == 0:
        return ans
    if targetSum <0:
        return None
    if targetSum in hmap:
        return hmap[targetSum]
    for len in numbers:
        remainder = targetSum-len
        remainder_result = howSum(remainder,numbers,ans)
        if remainder_result != None:
            hmap[remainder]  = remainder_result
            ans.append(len)
            return ans
    return None
```